# Using CipherOutputStream in Java

Tags: java, jce, encryption

I'm trying to use an AES cipher to encrypt some bytes but it's returning a silent error, meaning I enter something like:

```
byte[] raw = new String("Test","UTF8").getBytes("UTF8");
```

and it won't return anything. I think the problem is the `ByteArrayInput`/`OutputStreams` but I don't know how to do it any other way..

Here's the code in question.

```
public byte[] encrypt(byte[] in) {
    byte[] encrypted = null;
    try {
        aesCipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        aesCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aeskeySpec);
        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(in);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(bais.available());
        CipherOutputStream os = new CipherOutputStream(baos, aesCipher);
        copy(bais, os);
        os.flush();
        byte[] raw = baos.toByteArray();
        os.close();
        encrypted = Base64.encodeBase64(raw);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FileEncryption.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FileEncryption.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InvalidKeyException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FileEncryption.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FileEncryption.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FileEncryption.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return encrypted;
}
```

Here's another function in the same class that does work:

```
public void encrypt(File in, File out) {


    try {
        aesCipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        aesCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aeskeySpec);
        FileInputStream is;
        is = new FileInputStream(in);
        CipherOutputStream os = new CipherOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(out), aesCipher);
        copy(is, os);
        os.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FileEncryption.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FileEncryption.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InvalidKeyException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FileEncryption.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FileEncryption.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FileEncryption.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}

private void copy(InputStream is, OutputStream os) throws IOException {
    int i;
    byte[] b = new byte[2048];
    while ((i = is.read(b)) != -1) {
        os.write(b, 0, i);
    }
}
```

Comment: since you're logging exception, what's in your log file?

Answer (score 2):

The first thing that catches my eye is this line:

aesCipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

Assuming `aesCipher` is a variable of type `Cipher`, you are calling here the static `Cipher.getInstance` and throwing away the result (not assigning it to any variable). I.e. this line has no effect at all, `aesCipher` is the same as before this line.

If it was `null` before, then it still is `null`, and the next line (which calls a non-static method) will give you a NullPointerException. If your code is silently gobbling unknown exceptions (this might be outside the code shown), this is a general problem.

Other than this, I suppose that the `flush` on the CipherOutputStream does not really flush the whole buffer, but only as many blocks that can be written without adding any padding. Use `close()` instead of `flush()` here (which also seems to work in the second example).

---

A general remark: A [small self-contained complete compilable example](http://sscce.org/) would have enabled me to try it and give you a definite answer, instead of only guessing. For example, "does not return anything" is not a good description for the behavior of your method - does the method return `null`, an empty array, throw an exception, block eternally?